# Cambodia Angkor Air: Da Nang to Siem Reap direct flights only until October 2023?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, vietnam, cambodia, siem-reap

I was looking for a direct flight from Da Nang (DAD) to Siem Reap (REP) in December, but it seems that there are no direct flights at all after October 15th 2023.

Is that really the case, does anyone know what's going on there, or why no company is taking up that route? Or will the flights be made available in the future, as it's too early now (September 2023) to buy those flights? It would seem to me that one month in the future is not a long time in advance...

Below a screenshot of Cambodia Angkor Air that shows daily flights until Oct 15th, then nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Siem Reap International Airport (REP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siem_Reap_International_Airport) is being [replaced](https://www.phnompenhpost.com/business/siem-reap-airport-close-after-new-one-opens) with [Siem Reap–Angkor International Airport (SAI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siem_Reap%E2%80%93Angkor_International_Airport). Cambodia Angkor Air will fly from [Da Nang International Airport (DAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Nang_International_Airport) to SAI from Oct 16, 2023, according to [Cambodia Angkor Air's official website](https://cambodiaangkorair.com/) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBomD.jpg)).