# Is Siem Reap (REP) open? Otherwise, how to access Angkor Wat?

Tags: airports, cambodia, siem-reap

Google does not show flights to/from Siem Reap (REP). Is that airport active?
If not, what is the best way access Angkor Wat?

Comment: [Cambodia Angkor Air: Da Nang to Siem Reap direct flights only until October 2023?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183432/cambodia-angkor-air-da-nang-to-siem-reap-direct-flights-only-until-october-2023)

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184323/cambodia-e-visa-new-sai-airport-missing-from-entry-port-list-can-i-use-rep Discussed there too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The old Siem Reap International Airport (REP) was closed in 2023, when the new Siem Reap–Angkor International Airport (SAI) opened.

Google Flights lists flights for the new SAI airport.